# not all code paths return a "value"

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to make a mastermind game where I having the user guess a number sequence between 4-10 instead of colours but for some reason my GetRandomNumberCount and my GenerateRandomNumber give me the error not all code paths return a value.

Any guidance would be appreciated

```
public static int GetRandomNumberCount()
{
      //Create the secret code
      Random RandomClass = new Random();

      int first = RandomClass.Next(1, 5);
      int second = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
      int third = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
      int forth = RandomClass.Next(1,5);

      Console.WriteLine ("You are playing with M@sterB@t");
      Console.WriteLine ("Bot Says : You Go First");
      Console.WriteLine("Game Settings ");
      Console.WriteLine("The Game Begins");
}
```

Comment: Only post the relevant code not your whole project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because they don't return a value. For example GetRandomNumberCount has `Int`set as its return type, but has no return statement. If you want to return nothing set the return type to void. Using that as an example

```
 public static int[] GetRandomNumberCount()
{
    //Create the secret code
    Random RandomClass = new Random();

    int first = RandomClass.Next(1, 5);
    int second = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
    int third = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
    int forth = RandomClass.Next(1,5);

    Console.WriteLine ("You are playing with M@sterB@t");
    Console.WriteLine ("Bot Says : You Go First");
    Console.WriteLine("Game Settings ");
    Console.WriteLine("The Game Begins");

    //This is where you would return a value, but in this case it seems you want to return an array of ints
    //Notice how I changed the return type of the method to Int[]
   int[] numbers = new int[4];
   numbers.Add(first);
   numbers.Add(second);
   numbers.Add(third);
   numbers.Add(fourth);

   //This is the actual return statement that your methods are missing
   return numbers;

    }
```

regardless of whether you actually want to return an int array is moot though, Im only guessing. The real take away is that the `int[]` in

```
public static int[] GetRandomNumberCount()
```

declares a return type meaning you need a a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error cause your method signature says it returns a `int` but your are not returning anything. What I see is, you meant to have a method with `void` return type like below since you are just printing the lines

```
public static void GetRandomNumberCount()
{
      //Create the secret code
      Random RandomClass = new Random();

      int first = RandomClass.Next(1, 5);
      int second = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
      int third = RandomClass.Next(1,5);
      int forth = RandomClass.Next(1,5);

      Console.WriteLine ("You are playing with M@sterB@t");
      Console.WriteLine ("Bot Says : You Go First");
      Console.WriteLine("Game Settings ");
      Console.WriteLine("The Game Begins");
}
```

Comment: he clearly wants to return those ints though, otherwise they were created for noting and then just go out of scope

Comment: @psoshmo, that's just a speculation at this point in time unless OP clears it. Moreover, how you think you will return all of the random numbers?

Comment: in an int array, but yea youre right, I am assuming at this point, which I should not do.